# Using Android 2.0 with Exchange server behind firewall

Tags: exchange, android

Blackberry has an enterprise server that works with MS Exchange, and pushes all updates to the user's blackberry devices. We are considering switching to Android phones, which supposedly support Exchange servers. Will there be a similar program for Android? Are there any configuration changes that have to be done on Exchange server? (Exchange is behind the corp firewall).

Answer (score 4):

The aforementioned NitroDesk TouchDown should do the job, but HTC and possibly other Android phones have the ability to sync onboard already.

Setting up can be a little tricky, but here is a massive tip that will almost certainly help you get it working: use https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ to test for ActiveSync connectivity, if it fails it often gives you a reason and almost always a solution to go with it.

Comment: +1 for bringing up TestExchangeConnectivity.com - it really is a great tool provided by Microsoft.

Comment: That testing tool helped, along with this article from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817379. It does talk about disabling SSL but I know Android 2.3.3 has an issue with exchange ssl that was fixed in Android 2.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Nitrodesk Touchdown](http://www.nitrodesk.com/) on mine.  I have found better with Exchange than my blackberry for me.  The whole Android experience is a little rough around the edges though, everything isn't as integrated as the BB.  To get the updates right away, you just need ActiveSync enabled on the Exchange server.

I used this 'work email' client with Exchange that was available, but that wasn't as feature rich.  I don't think Android 2.0 is released yet, so I don't think you will hear a lot about how it works in an enterprise setting.

Comment: I missed mentioning it yesterday, but happy belated 10K day.

Comment: Android 2.0 is the OS of the new Motorola Droid phone that is on Verizon so its is out now.  Supposably the HTC Eris will also get an upgrade once they work out some bugs with their SenseUI

Answer (score 1):

As said before there is Active Sync.  But before swapping out all your phones, buy a couple and setup a couple of people with them.  That will let you see what it takes to set them up.  Have a couple of the user's use them as their only phone/organizer for a couple of weeks and see what they think of it.  Ideally use the lowest tech users you have, since they would have the most trouble changing.  Have them put together a quick list of things they liked and didn't like for everyone else, If they like it and are happy, the likely everyone else will too. If they hated it, it might be worth re-considering the change.  Or offer people the option.

Answer (score 0):

For heavy MS Exchange user, they should stick with Windows Mobile. Nothing other then WM provide full support. i.e. two way inbox/sent item sync, multi calendars, private items, GAL. 
However, the most important thing is that you don't need any APP to be installed on your device. AND, you don't need to install any Server side software. AND, the initial setup on WM device could be as little as 30 sec. AND, there should be less tech support calls. AND potentially less cost. And potentially quicker and better support on newer Exchange versions.
The only down side is... it's not "iPhone", "BlackBerry", and others will start to question about why you don't use those,

Comment: This is an entirely subjective response to your subjective answer - but very few people that I know with WinMo phones were happy with them, compared to users of BB.